# Flash Shared Objects Storage Location Changing Occasionally

Tags: apache-flex, flash, shared-objects

When running a flash application that I run locally

ie I get to it from a browser but with a file path

file:///C:/Projects/test/bin-debug/Main.html#

Now, most of the time the shared objects are stored in

%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player#SharedObjects\XXXX#localWithNet

But occasionally, it reverts and thinks this application is running on localhost

%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player#SharedObjects\XXXX\localhost

which means all previous saved settings are gone.

I'm wondering if anyone knows how flash decides if the application is infact localhost or localWithNet (local with Network access)

Rebooting can sometimes make it revert, but I've also had it stay localhost for a few days then revert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it has everything to do with your 'domain'.  If you're running in a browser with `file://pathToSwf/YourSwf.swf`, that's normally localWithNet, if you're doing `http://localhost/YourSwf.swf`, that's localhost domain.  I don't think there's any other way for this to happen unless you're doing something funky, but then I don't know that since I need more details.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but it does happen. Im really not sure why.

Comment: There are no more details. I always run from a file:// path, but sometimes it looses all my settings which are saved in stored objects. Under investigation I find it is now using localhost shared objects rather than localWithNet

Comment: Go to the [Flash Player Security Settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) and add the swf and the folder that you're running from as a trusted location.  It might fix your issue.  Other than that, I would look at the code.  Could be that somewhere, something is specifying localhost and confusing the Flash Player.  A sure way to fix it would be to use a webserver to serve your files over localhost.